# For USB-C, is it compliant to use the SBU pins for low voltage serial data transfer during 20 V Power Delivery?

Tags: usb-c, power-delivery

I'd like to use a PD controller to allow for 20 V, 60 W+ to enter the sink system, but I'd also like to use the sideband pins (or other pins) to send some 3.3 V TTL serial data to the host side in the meantime.

I'd like to know if this is possible (seems like PD doesn't use SBU pins to deliver power), and whether this use of SBU during PD is compliant with USB-C specs.

Comment: Your device must have the pins floating/disconnected until both devices agree to be in same mode where they know which pins are used and how. For example Type-C has a "Debug Adapter" mode.